# pl /sql set ORA-00922: missing or invalid option on set serveroutput on;

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
set serveroutput on;

DECLARE 
 message varchar2(20):= 'Hello, World!';

BEGIN dbms_output.put_line(message); 
END; 
/
```

Comment: Which tool / application the code is run from? `set serveroutput on` works fine in SQL* Plus / SQL developer only and is not part of SQL or PL/SQL language

Comment: how in pl/sql msg will display?

Comment: PL/SQL is a language not a tool. As already mentioned in an answer your code works fine if run from SQL* plus or even from SQL developer. But, looking at the error message, that doesn't seem to be the case . So, tell us how  exactly  are you running this PL/SQL code?

Comment: i am running it in toad using pl/sql style sheet

Comment: @shabanaAfzal You mention that you are using toad. You have to use the lightning bolt instead of the green triangle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others have indicated "set server output on" is a SQL*Plus command. If you need that functionality in plsql the you're looking for is DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE. Your above block becomes:

```
declare 
  message varchar2(20) := 'Hello World';
begin 
  dbms_output.enable;
  dbms_output.put_line(message);
end ;
```

Comment: i am facing one more problem in creating procedure .procedure get created but at execution time when i enter parameter value i get error  same application i am using .                                                                        create or replace procedure test
(supplierid in number  ,
supplier out varchar  ) 
is 
begin 
select FIRST_NAME into Supplier from lup_sup_master
where sup_id=supplierid ;
end;
-----
execute test(:supplierid);

Comment: Where can i see this output working? I tried sql dev and sqlplus, it doesn't crash, but the output does not appear either. I'm i missing something?

Comment: DBMS_OUTPUT doesn't actually output anything, it creates a buffer for the client to access, [see dbms_output.get_line](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a68001/dbms_out.htm). The client reads that buffer, but first must initiate that functionality. In SQLplus run SET SERVEROUTPUT ON before the plsql is run,  In sql developer select View->dbms_output then in the resulting window click the yellow **+** and select your schema in the resulting dialog. Other IDEs will have a similar method on enabling dbms_output.

Answer (score 1):

If use SQL*plus then this code works fine.

```
[oracle@krw-sql-ora12-01 ~]$ sqlplus scott/tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Fri Feb 22 08:07:25 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> set serveroutput on;

SQL> DECLARE
  2   message varchar2(20):= 'Hello, World!';
  3  BEGIN dbms_output.put_line(message);
  4  END;
  5  /
Hello, World!

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you used `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` within the PL/SQL procedure (or an anonymous block), e.g.

```
SQL> begin
  2    set serveroutput on;
  3  end;
  4  /
  set serveroutput on;
      *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 7:
PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


SQL>
```

Perhaps you didn't post everything you really have; is that `SET` command part of a *larger* procedure? If so, move it out.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you are using toad. You have to use the lightning bolt instead of the green triangle. Hover your mouse over the two icons. You will see the green triangle says: Execute/compile statement at caret. You will see the lightning bolt says: Execute as script.

```
set serveroutput on;

DECLARE 
 message varchar2(20):= 'Hello, World!';

BEGIN dbms_output.put_line(message); 
END; 
/
```

[image]

Comment: Please share code as formatted text instead of screenshots.